# Do we allow these type of questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have flagged two questions and would like to know if I did the right thing by flagging them

[How To create a sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248804/how-to-create-a-fixed-size-twitter-bootstrap-text-area)
[How to get a sidebar in smartphone fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279434/how-to-get-a-fixed-sidebar-to-display-nicely-when-viewed-from-a-smartphone)

Can anyone provide some insight on these type of questions?  I feel they need to be closed.

Comment: Why do you feel they needed to be closed?

Comment: The answers can be found everywhere on SO and google and even on Bootstrap site . Or do we allow questions which show no research effort and for the sake of posting code .. they post two or 3 lines and ask everyone to lend in and answer them .

Comment: The first question shows no effort. I would close it.

Comment: @MathieuImbert the second question  which is too basic and on searching on stackoverflow , anyone with a no knowledge background can understand the basic of media queries and its usage .

Comment: @MathieuImbert 2nd question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meh, I've seen a lot worse.

The first question is a bit underspecified and poorly-written, which probably explains the downvotes.

The second one seems OK.  To a certain extent, [we love duplicates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/); unless they are clearly duplicating identical information, they help to broaden the depth of questions and answers, and improve the Google search experience.

Whatt may seem obvious to you may not seem so obvious to someone else, and unless you already know what a Media Query is, you might not know how to get there from a Google Search.

Comment: If the same would have been asked by a new user , I am sure he would have got lot many down votes .. Both of these questions have answers on stackoverflow and doesnt need answer just because he tweaked one word .

Comment: Read the blog post I linked.

Comment: if he would have posted half of the question title in google or stackcoverflow he would have got lot many answers well written than he has now . And on his part doesnt show any research .. he didnt posted I tried this and this is wat happens and I am stuck here. Isnt it .. or M I lookin at it the wrong way

Comment: Did you read the blog post?  Did you read the last paragraph in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did ... and Got your point .Thanks for the well written info . BTW  The second question is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542295/bootstrap-responsive-affixed-menu